# router.push electron-vue doesn't work if mainwindow is hidden

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron, vue-router

I've an app built with **Electron** and **Vuejs** / **Vue-router**.

In my electron's **index.js**  I have this function, for hide the window once time I've opened the app.

```
mainWindow.hide();
```

I have also a Splash-Page built with Vuejs that make a redirect if user is Logged, some like:

```
if(this.isLogged()){
   this.$router.push({name: 'logged-view'})
}else{
   this.$router.push({name: 'login-view'})
}
```

My problem is that if I hide my window with **mainWindow.hide()** the Splash-Page make a push of route but it will never create a component (login-view or logged-view).
Instead if I remove mainwindow.hide() the app redict towards my component correctly.

Yes I can hide window once time I am in the new component after redirect, it isn't the behavior that I would have.

So is there a way for redirect if mainwindow is hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For others Developers:

I've solved.

I don't call a **mainwindow.hide()** anymore, but I have put in my **browserwindow** creation:

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    height: 563,
    useContentSize: true,
    width: 1000,
    show:false // this for solve the problem of router.push() avoid mainwindow.hide()
  })
```